# How to stop brightness changes (screen dimming) on low battery?

Tags: 14.10, laptop, power-management, brightness, battery

Ubuntu 14.10 automatically adjusts screen brightness on low battery. It does so despite explicitly being set not to.

[image: Brightness and Lock setting in Ubuntu 14.10 with "Dim screen to save power unchecked]

How to prevent this behaviour? I'd like the brightness to stay on the manually set level all the way to the bitter end (of battery life).

Comment: At what point in the battery life does it dim?

Comment: @Tim 5% and then again at 3%, I bevelie. What's even more annoying, it also does it in reverse: when charging it will dim once or twice.

Comment: I dont know if you can remove that deep down behaviour like that... It is because it doesn't want data lost / HDD damaged, so it takes desperate measures. The option you ticked was to not dim when it is on battery vs power.

Comment: Really? @Tim, how does power loss cause HDD damage?

Comment: @JellicleCat No idea, does it?

Comment: @Tim, I didn't believe that it did, but I interpreted your language to mean it was so: "it doesn't want data lost / HDD damaged, so it takes desperate measures."

Comment: @JellicleCat I could be totally wrong there, I have no idea :) That was a year ago!